# Synchronize blur and click events in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, synchronization, onblur

I am finding it difficult to synchronize blur and click events. The scenario is as follows: I have a page in which i have a textbox and a button. Now I have a blur event handler for the textbox, which basically makes an AJAX request and updates some part of the page. Also I have a click handler for the button which does some other job.

Now the problem here is that since I have a blur event handler on the textbox, when I enter something in the text box and directly click the button, it fires both blur and click events (as expected). The problem is synchronizing the two since the click handler should only execute once the blur handler has returned (if there was any blur event).

Sample code is as follows:

```
 $('#textbox').on('blur', function(){
//make an ajax request
});

$('#btn').on('click',function(){
//wait for the blur event to finish(if any) 
// then execute the code
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/8m7j5/2/

```
var blurring = [];
var expecting = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#textbox').on('blur', function () {
        // make an ajax request

        console.log("TEXTBOX BLURRED");

        blurring.push(1);    // Flag a new blur event

        $.ajax({
            url: "/echo/json/",
            complete: function () {
                setTimeout(function () {    // Simulate AJAX request taking 2 seconds
                    console.log("AJAX REQUEST COMPLETE");
                    blurring.pop();    // Flag completed blur event
                    checkClick();
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
    });

    $('#btn').on('click', function () {
        // wait for the blur event to finish(if any)
        // then execute the code

        console.log("ACTUALLY CLICKED BUTTON");

        expecting = true;
        checkClick();
    });
});

function checkClick() {
    if (expecting && blurring.length < 1) {
        console.log("CHECKING: EXPECTING CLICK AND NO MORE BLUR EVENTS");
        expecting = false;
        clickFunction();
    } else {
        console.log("CHECKING: EITHER NOT EXPECTING OR BLUR EVENT(S) STILL OCCURRING");
    }
}

function clickFunction() {
    console.log("EXECUTING CLICK FUNCTION");

    // Put your actual click code here
}
```

What you actually want to happen when the button is clicked, put in `clickFunction`.

Comment: Though i was looking for something which actually synchronizes the events, but this solves the problem for the time being, thanks ian and krypthonite for looking into this. But i am still facing an issue with jquery ui dialog, which seems to block the click event, actually i am showing a loader made of jquery ui dialog while ajax is going on, but when i use it, the click event is never fired, it seems to be blocking the click event, any idea how this can be resolved ?

Comment: @vijaytyagi Well, I think this is the best you can do (the logic I proposed, not the exact code) to "synchronize" because there is no real synchronization that I know of. What do you mean the click event is being "blocked" though? In what way? Do you have a jsFiddle set up to demonstrate your scenario?

Answer (score 2):

The code from ianpgall a bit improved:

```
var functionsToCall = [];
var ajaxRunning = false;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#textbox').on('blur', function(){
        ajaxRunning = true;
        console.log("START AJAX REQUEST");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/echo/json/",
            complete: function () {
                setTimeout(function () {    // Simulate AJAX request taking 2 seconds
                    console.log("AJAX REQUEST COMPLETE");
                    ajaxRunning = false;
                    fireStackedCalls();
                }, 5000);
            }
        });
    })

    $('#btn').on('click',function(){
        if(ajaxRunning === true) {
            functionsToCall.push('clickFunction()');
        } else {
            clickFunction();
        }
    });

    function fireStackedCalls() {
        while(functionsToCall.length > 0) {
            toCall = functionsToCall.pop();
            eval(toCall);
        }
    }

    function clickFunction() {
        console.log("EXECUTING CLICK FUNCTION");

        // Put your actual click code here
    }
});
```

Now every call of the clickFunction is recorded and executed if the ajax request is done.